# Cannot print code received by client using sockets in C

Tags: c, sockets, server, client, buffer

I don know why i can't print the information saved into my client's buffer. Firstly, the code i'm transfering from server to client is the source code of google main page. I've saved this code in a html file and the size of the whole file is 198357 bytes.
For this, i used a buffer of 1024 bytes and i've passed all the data inside loops.

I've been checking using prints the number of bytes passed by the server and received by client and both are equal to the number of bytes of the file, so the transferation is well done.
But when i try to print this data saved into the buffer it starts giving me problems.

**server.c**

```
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main(void)
{
    struct sockaddr_in serverAddress;
    serverAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverAddress.sin_addr.s_addr=INADDR_ANY;
    serverAddress.sin_port = htons(9999);


    int server = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    if(server == -1)
    {
        perror("Cannot open the socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    int active = 1;
    setsockopt(server, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &active, sizeof(active));
    if(bind(server, (void*)&serverAddress, sizeof(serverAddress)) !=0) 
    {
        perror("Fail bind");
        exit(1);    
    }
    else
    {
        printf("success\n");
    }


    printf("I'm listening\n");

    listen(server, SOMAXCONN); 

//----------------------------------------------------

    while(1)
    {
        struct sockaddr_in clientAddress;
        unsigned int addressSize;
        int client = accept(server, (struct sockaddr*)&clientAddress, &addressSize);

        int child = fork();
        if(child==0) //in case we stablished a connection we have to create a child and then transfer the file inside of it
        {
            int file = open("google.html",O_RDONLY); //open file

            if(file <0)
            {
                perror("Empty file!\n");
                return 1;
            }

            while(1) //Iterate until function read cannot read more bytes
            {
                unsigned char buffer[1024]={0};
                int read_bytes = read(file,buffer,sizeof(buffer));

                if(read_bytes==0)
                {
                    printf("Transfer!\n");
                    break;
                }
                while(read_bytes>0) //Write on the client the reading bytes
                {
                    int written_bytes;
                    written_bytes = write(client, buffer, read_bytes);
                    //printf("%d\n",written_bytes); //print to check how many bytes are passed to the client (1024)


                    read_bytes -= written_bytes; //breaks loop
                }               
            } 
        }

        close(server); 
        shutdown(server, SHUT_RDWR);
        sleep(1);
        break;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

**client.c**

```
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(int argc, char* argv)
{
    if(argc ==2) //you've got to received as an argument the IP of the server, i haven't implemented it yet!
    {

        int client = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
        char recvBuffer[1024];
        int n=0, s;
        if(client <0)
        {
            printf("Cannot open the socket\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        struct sockaddr_in serverAddress;
        serverAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
        serverAddress.sin_addr.s_addr=INADDR_ANY;
        serverAddress.sin_port = htons(9999);


        if(connect(client, (void*)&serverAddress, sizeof(serverAddress)) !=0)
        {
            perror("Cannot be connected");
            return 1;
        }

        printf("Connecting!");
        char buffer2[1024];
        while((n=read(client, recvBuffer,sizeof(recvBuffer)-1))>0)
        {
            //printf("%d\n",n); //i used to check the num of bytes passed by this and everything it's correct
            recvBuffer[n] =0; 
            printf("%s",recvBuffer); //error, the transferation goes wrong here
        }


        if(n==0)
        {
            shutdown(client, SHUT_RD);
            close(client);  
        }
        else if(n<0)
        {
              perror("Read error\n");
              return 1;  
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Would you mind to tell us more about "it starts giving me problems"? What kind of problems? What is printed?

Comment: yeah, as you can see i print the number of bytes passed by the server to check everything it's okay. So, when i try to print the buffer too, the number of bytes is equal to -1. That mean the write function is not working correctly and i dont know why. And well the buffer is never printed.

Comment: Are you saying that `written_bytes` in the server is -1?

Comment: yeah! that's exactly what happens! Moreover, in the while i use to read data in **client.c** if you comment the printf of the buffer and uncomment `printf("%d \n", n)` you will see the transferation has no problems! The written and read bytes by the server and client print perfectly. I think i haven't explained that correctly sorry